# NSTableView does not call function

Tags: swift, macos-sierra

I am trying to populate a simply view based NSTableView in a macOS application. I have set the delegate and datasource on the storyboard. I have added this little extension language. When I load the view, func numberOfRows is called and those are added to the tableView, but the function to build the cell value is never called.

I am not sure I have this correct for NSTableView but this basic code works great for iOS apps. I am new to Swift and just cannot seem to get this to work properly.

Any advice?

```
extension LAManagerVC: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        print ("My Activity Count: \(myActivities.count)")
        return myActivities.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?{

        print ("Hello world")
        let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
        cell?.textField?.stringValue = myActivities[row].title
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: This is apparently a bug. This is 2023 and the bug still exists. I love how Apple treats developers. Developing for Apple is 2% writing code and 98% trying to solve poorly written/documented APIs. And the gods help us when they try to write documentation: one trillion lines of code to explain how to set the color of a view, or something simple.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

From the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdatasource/1533674-tableview?language=objc):

```
table​View(_:​object​Value​For:​row:)​
```

> Called by the table view to return the data object associated with the
>   specified row and column.

### Solution

To display the cells use [table​View(_:​view​For:​row:​)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1527449-tableview) like this in your case:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
  print ("Hello world")
  let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
  cell?.textField?.stringValue = myActivities[row].title
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the function still does not get called. What is strange is that numberOfRows is being called like I would expect. It is returning back 3 values which is in myActivities. But the function for dealing with the cell values is not being called.

Comment: You said you set up the delegate and dataSource via the storyboard. Check it if you really have. Or just set it up via code in `viewDidLoad()` of `LAManagerVC` like this: `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: Thanks, it is, but this is loaded in a tab view item, so I think it is using the wrong view for the delegate. I believe that may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`objectValueFor` is supposed to return the item of the data source array for that specific row (and column), but **never** a cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    return myActivities[row]
}
```

If you are using Cocoa bindings, bind the UI elements to key path `objectValue.<property>`, if not implement `tableView:viewFor:row:` and set the values of the UI elements there.